# Can I get feedback on these failed review audits?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Recently, I failed these two review audits:

- [**A:** Must I implement Applicative and Functor to implement a Monad **[First Posts]**](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/8098447)

  This is a *very low quality* answer, isn't it? Shouldn't have it been posted as a comment?
- [**Q:** Truth value of numpy array with one falsey element seems to depend on dtype **[Triage]**](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8108749)

  This question has a lack of explanation, hasn't it? Isn't the title required to get the meaning, while it should only summarize the topic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This is a very low quality answer, isn't it? Shouldn't have it been posted as a comment?

What's low quality about it?  It answers the question.  It's certainly not a comment as it's not a clarifying question or anything like that; it's an answer to the question.  It's a short answer, but a perfectly fine answer.  There's no reason for it to be deleted.

> This question has a lack of explanation, hasn't it? Isn't the title required to get the meaning, while it should only summarize the topic?

I agree it could use a bit more explanation for it to be a *better* question.  I might even consider downvoting it, but I don't see any close criteria that it meets.  It's not sufficiently unclear as to merit closure for that reason.  And it being something that's *hard* but *possible* to understand would mean that I could see justification for Needs Improvement.  Particularly for issues like the question being in the title but not in the body; that's something that community members can fix with editing.  We have enough information to understand what it's asking, it just needs to be presented better.  It's very much not unsalvageable.

Comment: How exactly does the first item answer to the question?

Comment: @FrancescoMenzani How does it fail to answer the question?  The question asks, "Must I do X?" and the answer says, "Yes", explaining when the change took place, and providing a link for more information if the OP is curious as to why they must do X.  This is of course why I dislike yes/no questions.  People almost certainly mean to ask, "how" or "why" instead.